# VSTO Word Customisation Deployment Issue

Tags: xml, visual-studio, ms-word, xsd, vsto

I am attempting to create a word 2016 customisation using Visual Studio 2017 with VSTO. I wish to bind XML data to  a series of content controls, including drop down lists and define the allowable contents of the dropdowns.  I am following the guidance given by MS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-binding-content-controls-to-custom-xml-parts?view=vs-2017
and I publish this using Once Click and this all works well on my machine.
However, when I try and deploy this on another PC, the issue is that the XML Schema that I have defined is listed as unavailable on the target PC.  When I manually add the Schema (Developer->Word Add Ins->XML Schema->Add Schema) by selecting the xsd file containing in my VSTO solution, it all works.
So, my question is how can I configure a target PC to auto load the XML Schema into Word? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the .xsd file properties, select `Content` for `Build Action`. Then in the `Copy to Output Directory` select either `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

[image: screenshot]